# Python Websocket not running forever

Tags: python

my Python Websocket .py file closes on its own after like 10 days of leaving it on, even though I use **run_forever**.

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    msg = json.loads(message)
    #do stuff here

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)
    f = open("websocket_error.txt", "a") #log error
    f.write(error)
    time.sleep(1)
    run(endpoint) #re-run after 1 sec

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second ###")
    ws.close()

def on_open(ws):
    print("### open ###")

def run(endpoint):
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(endpoint,
                                on_open = on_open,
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close)

    ws.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":command = 'subscribe=trade:XBTUSD'
    endpoint = 'wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?'+command

    run(endpoint)
```

I've tried to see if the sudden close is caused by an error but there is nothing in the log. Has anybody had similar experience?

Comment: Forever isn't what it used to be :)

Comment: Forever and beyond

Comment: :P.. Any serious answer?

Comment: are you sure bitmex is not disconnecting you? What kind of logs have you checked ? Is it going to onClose or program crashing ? Is it every 10 days at specific time?

Comment: if its close what is the event code that you receive on close ?

Comment: @PraveenB Sorry I'm a complete noob. I don't really know how to retrieve the event code for on_close but I will try to google. Thanks !